# Vertical <ul> in horizontal <li>

Tags: html, css

I want to separate the screen into three columns using a `ul` tag, and I want to have a normal (vertical) list inside the first column. I tried this but it does not work:

```html
<ul id="content_seperator">
  <li class="content_left">
    <ul id="vertical-nav">
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li> Menu2 </li>
      <li> Menu3 </li>
      <li> Menu4 </li>
      <li> Menu5 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="content_middle"></li>
  <li class="content_right"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add css code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. I hope it helps.

```css
#content_seperator,
  .content_left,
  .content_middle,
  .content_right {
      display: flex;
  }
  .content_left,
  .content_middle,
  .content_right {
      flex: 1 1 0
  }
```

```html
<ul id="content_seperator">
    <li class="content_left">
        <ul id="vertical-nav">
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li> Menu2 </li>
            <li> Menu3 </li>
            <li> Menu4 </li>
            <li> Menu5 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="content_middle">Middle</li>
    <li class="content_right">Right</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use,

```
#content_seperator{
  display: block;
}
#content_seperator li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#content_seperator li ul li{
  display: block;
}
```

you can give width for 'li' by using class.